# Error when iframe website using dns Cloudflare

Tags: html, iframe, https, dns, cloudflare

I am using services DNS of Cloudflare. I want iframe my website in another domain. 
When i used code

```
<iframe src="https://tcwebvn.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

I get an error white page.
Help me find problem!

Comment: Sounds like your browser is out of date. Also, if you are loading your iFrame via *HTTPS* rather than HTTP, all your assets on your page must also be loaded via HTTPS, or they will fail to load as the browser will treat them as insecure content.

Comment: What errors the console display?

Answer (score 3):

Your site is explicitly preventing framing on other sites by sending an X-Frame-Options HTTP header of SAMEORIGIN: https://securityheaders.io/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftcwebvn.com

Not sure if this is you setting this header or Cloudflare but either way it needs to be turned off to allow framing.

Framing can be a security risk (e.g. imagine a phishing site framing a well known banking site but putting its own username and password field hovering over the real ones) so this HTTP Header allows you to prevent that. You'll need to stop sending it to allow framing. There is an ALLOW-FROM option to allow you to explicitly state which sites you will let frame you but it's not very well supported and is being phased out in place of Content Security Policy (aka CSP).